# Resource recommendation for machine learning

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, computer

I am planning to change my field (in PhD) and learn Machine Learning to differentiate different phases of strongly correlated matter. I learned Monte Carlo method in my MS and have intermediate level knowledge of topological insulators.

Before completely getting into Machine Learning, I want to go-through an introductory level book/article on Machine learning for physicists. I want to know if it is too difficult for me to learn. (is it really very difficult?)

Do you know any books/articles in which Machine Learning is explained in the context of Physics?

Comment: I don't have any idea of Machine Learning and I work with simple model systems so that analytical results can be obtained either perturbatively or exactly. But this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157319300766?via%3Dihub) is tempting to be a good read.

Comment: take a look at this question on Math SE: [What is a good book for math students to learn machine learning in depth?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857677/157643)

Answer (score -1):

To start with this domain, first of all you should be working with Python Programming. In Python, the dedicated library for ML is available like SCIKIT-LEARN

Answer (score -2):

The following book might help you.
It covers the following:

1. Supervised Machine Learning Algorithms
2. Unsupervised Machine
3. Learning Algorithms
4. Semi Supervised Machine Learning Algorithms
5. Random Forest Algorithms
6. Support Vector Machine Algorithms
7. Artificial Neural Network Algorithms
8. Regression Algorithms
9. Clustering Algorithms
10. Resampling Algorithms
11. Association Rule Algorithm

Reference:

- Machine Learning: An overview with the help of R software
  ISBN: 978-1790122622
  https://books.google.com/books/about/Machine_Learning_An_overview_with_the_he.html?id=NDF7DwAAQBAJ